# Using jsPDF with Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am wondering if it is possible to incorporate [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) in a Google Apps Script project. I am trying to use templated HTML to generate documents and some CSS styles do not convert to pdf when using the `getAs()` function (mainly background-color). I know GAS has its javascript limitations so if anyone with more knowledge has any insight that would be great. Any other suggestions are welcome also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jsPDF in an html file inside google sheets scripts. I am using it right now to create a pdf. If you use this script tag inside your `<head>` tags in a html page:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.debug.js"></script>`

Then you would use this between script tags to create a pdf:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
    doc.save('test.pdf);
</script>
```